# update magento customer programmatically

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to modify existing customers data on magento programmatically, but i have errors, hope someone can help me with this.

```
require_once('../app/Mage.php');
ini_set("error_reporting",E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",true);
umask (0);
Mage::app('admin');

$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$firstname = $_REQUEST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_REQUEST['lastname'];
$newEmail = $_REQUEST['newEmail'];
$method = $_REQUEST['method'];
$user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id'];


$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
        $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
        $customer->loadByEmail($email);
        $customer->setFirstname = $firstname; 
        $customer->setLastname = $lastname; 
        $customer->setEmail = $newEmail; 
        $customer->save();
```

Here is the error message

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Customer_Exception' with message 'Customer email is required' in /home/insateck/www/zzWEBS/MAGENTO/ZZpruebasEXPRIMENET/app/Mage.php:580 Stack trace: #0 /home/insateck/www/zzWEBS/MAGENTO/ZZpruebasEXPRIMENET/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php(76): Mage::exception('Mage_Customer', 'Customer email ...') 
#1 /home/insateck/www/zzWEBS/MAGENTO/ZZpruebasEXPRIMENET/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1122): Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer->_beforeSave(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer)) 
#2 /home/insateck/www/zzWEBS/MAGENTO/ZZpruebasEXPRIMENET/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer))
#3 /home/insateck/www/zzWEBS/MAGENTO/ZZpruebasEXPRIMENET/syncadaptax/update_client_methods.php(33): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save() 
#4 {main} thrown in /home/insateck/www/zzWEBS/MAGENTO/ZZpruebasEXPRIMENET/app/Mage.php on line 580
```

Comment: What's the output of var_dump($_REQUEST['newEmail']);?

Comment: The output is string(testnewemail@test.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify the condition for saving the new email as:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer->loadByEmail($email);
if($customer->getId()>1){
     $customer2 = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
     $customer2->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
     $customer2->loadByEmail($newEmail);
     if($customer2->getId()<1){
        $customer->setEmail($newEmail); 
     }
     $customer->setFirstname($firstname); 
     $customer->setLastname ($lastname); 
     $customer->save();
 }
```

The updated condition will avoid the fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

Modified code is

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
        $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
        $customer->loadByEmail($email);
        if($customer->getId()<1){
            $customer->setEmail($newEmail); 

    }
    $customer->setFirstname($firstname); 
        $customer->setLastname ($lastname); 
        $customer->save();
```

Comment: No I have this error `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Customer_Exception' with message 'This customer email already exists'` Im not sure i was clear; what im trying to do is to update an existing client, the name, last name or even, if its possible, the email

Comment: @Vincent setFirstname(), setLastname(), setEmail() are methods. Compare `$customer->setFirstname($firstname);` from the answer and yours `$customer->setFirstname = $firstname;`

Comment: @PavelNovitsky that new error is with the implementation of the answer... :(

Comment: Never mind the answer works great for the name and last name, but it does not update/modify the email...

Comment: i have busy,will reply later